# Difference between two localizations

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, local-rings

What is the difference between $\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}[y]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x)}$? To me they are both equal to:

$\{ \frac{f(x, y)}{g(x,y)} | g(0, y) \neq 0 \}$

Is this true and if it isn't can anyone provide any intuition as to why it isn't, please.

Comment: $\frac{1}{y}$ is not in the first, but is in the second, just as an example.

Comment: So is the first one simply $\{ \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x)} |g(0)≠0 \}$ and is my initial idea correct for the second?

Comment: Yes, that is the only difference.